# Checking reciever account activity in PayPal using API

Tags: api, paypal

I plan to use mass payments in PayPal.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/
Can I ask you a question: before creating payout I want to check reciever account (Determines whether the specified PayPal account's status is verified or unverified). I want to exclude the possibility of an error in payment.

*I see like this scenario*.
**Client**: Hi, can I add funds to my account?
**I**: What is your ID (Email\Phone)?
**Client**: Hmm.. hello@world.com
**I**: Ok. Pls wait a few second. I will check your account
**I**: (I search client account in PayPal) Yes. Your account is valid! How much do you want to add funds?
**Client**: 5 dollars.
**I**: Ok. Create payout!

Is it possible to make a similar scenario in API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Method **GetVerifiedStatus**.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/integration-guide/ACGettingStarted/?mark=GetVerifiedStatus#adaptive-accounts-methods